# Xamarin Forms won't build with MvvmCross (Android)

Tags: c#, mono, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

i have some trouble to build the android project with MvvmCross.
Before i added MvvmCross the project build without problem. Note my windows phone project runs also without error.

But after i added MvvmCross (3.2.2) i got this error:

```html
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2,2): Error: Exception while loading assemblies: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'Cirrious.MvvmCross, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e16445fd9b451819'. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?
Dateiname: "Cirrious.MvvmCross.dll"
   bei Xamarin.Android.Tuner.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference reference, ReaderParameters parameters)
   bei Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences(ICollection`1 assemblies, AssemblyDefinition assembly, Boolean topLevel)
   bei Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.Execute() (smenso.SmartService.Mobile.Android)
```

I' currently using:

- Xamarin Forms 1.2.3.6257
- Xamarin Studio 5.5.4
- MvvmCross 3.2.2

Thanks for help.

Comment: Maybe take a look a working sample - e.g. https://github.com/Cheesebaron/Xam.Forms.Mvx/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks Stuart,

after checking the differences of the solutions. I noticed that my project is missing the **MvvmCross.HotTuna.MvvmCrossLibraries**. This package is necessary for the Android project to build (so it seems). Even if it's not a dependency.

After adding this package via nuget, the Android project builds and works.